# Prove that $M = (1-m)A + mS$ is not diagonalizable for all $0\le m<1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the link matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
    1 & 1/2 & 0 \\  \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Show that $M = (1-m)A + mS$ (all $S_{ij} = 1/3$) is not diagonalizable for $0 \le m < 1$.

I am not sure how to do this. Help needed. thanks

Comment: Please show the own work, for instance, which is the situation for $m=0$? (Which are the eigenvalues of the corresponding matrix $M$, which are the eigenspaces to the eigenvalue $\ne 1$?

Comment: A good place to start would be to write the matrix $M=(1-m)A+mS$ explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

*Sketch of proof.* Note that $A$ is column-stochastic. Hence $M$ is a column-stochastic positive matrix and $1$ is a simple eigenvalue of $M$. Since the trace of $M$ is $m$, if $M$ is not diaogonalisable, the other eigenvalue must be $\frac{m-1}{2}$ of algebraic multiplicity $2$. Hence it suffices to show that
$$
(M-I)\left(M-\frac{m-1}{2}I\right)\ne0=(M-I)\left(M-\frac{m-1}{2}I\right)^2.
$$

Comment: May I ask what is meant by trace of M and how did u get (m-1)/2?

Comment: @Alexis The trace of a square matrix is equal to the sum of all diagonal elements. It is also equal to the sum of all eigenvalues (over the algebraic closure of the underlying field). In other words, the sum of all eigenvalues is equal to the sum of all diagonal elements.

Comment: thx. btw how do u know (M-I)(M-(m-1)/2*I) not equal to 0 whereas the right equation = 0 ?

Comment: @Alexis It's something that one needs to verify by direct calculation.